# Count read and write accesses to memory

Tags: memory, perf, numa

On a Linux machine, I need to count the number of `read` and `write` accesses to `memory` (DRAM) performed by a process. The machine has a NUMA configuration and I am binding the process to access memory from a single remote NUMA node using `numactl`. The process is running on CPUs in node 0 and accessing memory in node 1.

Currently, I am using [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) to count the number of `LLC load miss` and `LLC store miss` events to serve as an estimate for read and write accesses to memory. Because, I guessed LLC misses will need to be served by memory accesses. Is this approach correct i.e. is this event relevant ? And, are there any alternatives to obtain the `read` and `write` access information ?

Processor : Intel Xeon E5-4620
Kernel : Linux 3.9.0+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your hardware you should be able to acess performance counter located on the memory side, to exactly count memory accesses. On Intel processor, these events are called uncore events. I know that you can also count the same thing on AMD processors.

Counting LLC misses is not totally correct because some events such as the hardware prefetcher may lead a significant number of memory accesses.

Regarding your hardware, unfortunately you will have to use raw events (in the perf terminology). These events can't be generalized by perf because they are processor's specifics and as a consequence you will have to look into your processor's manual to find the raw encoding of the event to give to perf. For your Intel processor you should look at chapter 1`8.9.8 Intel® Xeon® Processor E5 Family Uncore Performance Monitoring Facility` and `CHAPTER 19 PERFORMANCE-MONITORING EVENTS` of the Intel software developer manual document available [here](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf) In these documents you'll need the exact ID of your processor that you can get using `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Added the relevant information. I am not sure about which performance counters are relevant for counting hardware prefetcher related events.